# How To Disable Button when editext is empty in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog

i want to disable send button if my msgtext(editext) is empty

i have a dialogbox which have edittext and send button

when dialog box is open

and check if edittext is empty then my button is disable

here is my code

```
public void openDialog(){


             dialog = new Dialog(CommentsActivity.this);
             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogcommentlayout);
             dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
             dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
             dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
             msgtext=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_sent_msg);
             msgtext.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
             checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
             //buttton for send comment
             send=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sent_msg);

             send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                    new sendReply().execute();

                }
            });
            mHlvSimpleList= (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.feedlist);
            mHlvSimpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Listview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            //asynktask to show feed comment in dialog

     }
   private  void checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){


         String s1 = msgtext.getText().toString().trim();


         if(s1.equals(""))
         {
             send.setEnabled(false);
         }
     }
```

when my debugger check

```
if(s1.equals(""))
             {
                 send.setEnabled(false);
             }
```

Giving error NULLPOINTER Exeption

at
send.setEnabled(false); this line ...

please tell me where i m doing wrong and what ?
 thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `send` `Button` is still null when you execute  `send.setEnabled(false);`, inside `checkFieldsForEmptyValues()`. You have to initialize it first, then execute that method, so it isn't null. Like this:

```
//buttton for send comment
send=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sent_msg);
checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
```

This will solve your `NullPointerException` issue.